# setContentView is not working with GoogleApiClient on release apk

Tags: java, android, google-play-games

I've implemented the Google Play Games API in my game recently, but some issues appeared after that.

The problem is for some reason my game is not loading my Custom View class when I start the aplication and call the method ***setContentView()*** but this only happens when I build the release version of the apk.

```
gv = new GameView(this);
setContentView(gv); //not loading on release version or if the debuggable is set to true in build.gradle
```

I also tryied to put this line on build.gradle

> debuggable false

the result was that the release version started working but with this line I cant upload it to playStore and the reason of this thread is obviusly because I need this working on the playStore.

Some Notes of test:

- The Google play services connects well both **release** and **debug** apks, but in release a black screen appears isntead of my GameView Class
- The setContentView() **doesn't** works when running the apk on **release** version or if the debuggable is set to true in build.gradle.
- The setContentView() **works fine** when running the apk on **debug** version
- The setContentView() **works fine** if I load a XML file in any situations (but my game doesnt uses any XMLs).

**Main Activity Class**

```
public class Main extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    GameView gv;

    public static DBHandler db;
    public static String version = "0.0.0";

    public static GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        fullScreen(true); //PRE ESTABELECE O TAMANHO DA TELA DEIXANDO NO FULLSCREEN PRIMEIRAMENTE

        (Toast.makeText(this, "inicializando GameView", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)).show();
        gv = new GameView(this);
        setContentView(gv);

        // Create the Google Api Client with access to the Play Games services
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                // add other APIs and scopes here as needed
                .setViewForPopups(gv)
                .build();
        // ...
        //setContentView(R.layout.loading_screen);

        db = new DBHandler(this);
        Log.w("Main", ""+db.getPointsCount()+" - registros encontrados.");

        //VERSAO ---
        PackageInfo pInfo = null;
        try {
            pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
            version = pInfo.versionName;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }// ...

    }

    protected void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        gv.relase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        fullScreen(hasFocus);
    }
    void fullScreen(boolean hasFocus){
        if (hasFocus) {
            final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);}
    }



    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        Log.e("Main","Conectando ao Google Play...");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

        Log.e("Main","Desconectado da google API PlayGames!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.e("Main","onConnected");
        Games.Achievements.unlock(mGoogleApiClient, "CgkI8au7i4oUEAIQAg");

        (Toast.makeText(this, "Conectado ao Google Play Game", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)).show();


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.e("Main","onConnectionSuspended");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e("Main","onConnectionFailed");
        (Toast.makeText(this, "Não foi posivel conectar ao Google Play Services.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)).show();
    }

}
```

**Build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        DannarkKey {
            keyAlias 'dannark'
            keyPassword '23021994'
            storeFile file('C:/Users/Daniel/AndroidstudioProjects/DannarkKey.jks')
            storePassword '23021994'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jumpers.gamelogic"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 24
        versionName "2.7.4"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
}
```

**GameView.class**

```
/**
 * Created by Daniel on 19/03/2016.
 */
public class GameView extends View implements Runnable {
    Context context;
    private static final int INTERVAL = 10;
    private boolean running = true;
    private Paint p;
    public static HUD hud;
    public static PrintText pt;
    public static ArrayList<SpawnMessageWindows> spawnMsgs = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ScoreScreen scoreScreen;
    public static HandleEventsTouchsSpawnedObjects handleEventsTouchs = new HandleEventsTouchsSpawnedObjects();

    public static Load load;
    public static Fase fase;
    public static Player player;
    public static Menu menu;
    public static Camera cam;

    Bitmap layerImg2;
    public static Canvas layer2;
    public static LaterCanvas laterCanvas;

    public static int lar;
    public static int alt;

    public static int touchFocus = 0;

    public static ArrayList<String> variaveisName = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<Float> variaveisValue = new ArrayList<>();

    private long preTime = 0;
    public static int timeInGame = 0;

    public static boolean isPlaying = false;

    // blocksIDsUsedForTutorial TEM O OBJETIVO DE MOSTRAR MENSSAGENS DE TUTORIAS PELA PRIMEIRA VES CASO VC NUNCA TENHA USADO
    // UM SCRIPT, SE TIVER DENTRO DESSA LISTA, ENTÃO A MENSAGEM NAO APARECERA.
    public static ArrayList<Integer> blocksIDsUsedForTutorial = new ArrayList<>();

    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;

        load = new Load(context);

        p = new Paint();
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        t.start();
        preTime = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;

        addVariavel("variavel1", 0); //TESTE
        addVariavel("valor3", 0); //TESTE
        addVariavel("valor4", 0); //TESTE
        addVariavel("valor5", 0); //TESTE
        addVariavel("valor6", 0); //TESTE
        addVariavel("valor7", 0); //TESTE
        addVariavel("valor8", 0); //TESTE
    }

    void init(){
        while (getWidth() == 0){ }//aguarndando getWidth
        lar = getWidth();
        alt = getHeight();
        player = new Player();
        fase = new Tutorial_001(context);//new Fase1(context);
        hud = new HUD();
        pt = new PrintText();
        menu = new Menu(context);
        cam = new Camera(getWidth(), getHeight(), player);

        layerImg2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(lar, alt, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        layer2 = new Canvas(layerImg2);
        laterCanvas = new LaterCanvas(context);

        setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                //int action = event.getActionMasked();

                TextKeyBoard.handleTouch(v, event);
                NumericKeyBoard.handleTouch(v, event);
                hud.handleTouch(v, event);
                menu.handleTouch(v, event);
                cam.handleTouch(v, event);
                handleEventsTouchs.handleTouch(v, event); //SEGURA TODOS OS EVENTOS DE OBJETOS CRIADOS POSTEIORMENTE

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        init();

        while (running){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(INTERVAL);
            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Game Loop:"+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                t.show();
                Log.e("GameLogic", "GameLoop erro Inesperado: "+e.getMessage());
            }
            update();
        }
    }

    public void update(){
        //dispara o metodo de desenho
        postInvalidate();
        timeInGame = (int)((System.currentTimeMillis()/1000)-preTime); //TEMPO JOGADO EM SEGUNDOS
    }

    public void draw(Canvas c){
        super.draw(c);
        if(c!=null && player != null && hud != null && menu != null && cam!=null) {
            c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

            if(isPlaying) {
                cam.draw(c, p);

                hud.draw(c, p);
                pt.draw(c, p);

                if(scoreScreen != null) {
                    scoreScreen.draw(c);
                }

                laterCanvas.drawBeforeMsgs(c); //DESENHA TODOS OS DESENHOS SOBREPOSTOS NA MESMA CANVAS.

                if(spawnMsgs.size() > 0){
                    spawnMsgs.get(0).draw(c, p);
                }

                laterCanvas.drawAfterMsgs(c); //DESENHA TODOS OS DESENHOS SOBREPOSTOS NA MESMA CANVAS.
                //c.drawBitmap(layerImg2,0,0,p);

            }else {
                menu.draw(c, p);
            }
        }
    }

    public void relase(){
        running = false;
    }

    public static void addVariavel(String variavelNome, float variavelValor){
        if(variaveisName.contains(variavelNome) == false) {
            variaveisName.add(variavelNome);
            variaveisValue.add(variavelValor);
        }
    }
    public static void removeVariavel(int index){
        variaveisName.remove(index);
        variaveisValue.remove(index);
    }
    public static void setVariavelValor(int valiavelIndex, float variavelValor){
        variaveisValue.set(valiavelIndex, variavelValor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the error logs when using the release apk? 
Also, how long have you been using the release apk? If it's over a year, you may need to generate a new one.

Comment: I'm not able to see the erros in log cat when I use the release version unless if the debuggable is set to true in build.gradle, when I do that the works fine with google API but Im not able to upload it to playstore. Im not using this for too long this bug started yesterday  (My game is not published yet it is on beta test)

Comment: if you like, you can test it from [store](https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.jumpers.gamelogic) <- this is the version with the "error".
And here is the one that works well but I cant publish on store this because it is debuggable: [drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9LRSxhWQZAIaWtnMGdJNGxQLVE) the only change here was that I set the debuggable to true in gradle. :(

Comment: Im not 100% sure about this but can you try the Proguard settings [in this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923123/google-play-says-my-apk-built-with-android-studio-build-generate-signed-apk-is). Also, in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23005084/app-on-release-crashes-while-on-debug-doesnt), you seem to share a similar issue and it also indicates that Proguard is the one causing the error in release key mode. Kindly check it out.

Comment: Looks like im getting some erros when I try to put that code... see the [screenshots](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9LRSxhWQZAIaGdaeURGT28yYzg)